# Reactive streams publisher from Vertx webclient response body

Tags: java, rx-java, vert.x, reactive-streams, vertx-httpclient

I'm trying to write a wrapper for the Vert.x [web-client](https://vertx.io/docs/vertx-web-client/java/) to load response body from server using `Publisher` from reactivestreams:

```java
import org.reactivestreams.Publisher;
import io.vertx.reactivex.ext.web.client.WebClient;

interface Storage {
  Publisher<ByteBuffer> load(String key);
}

class WebStorage implements Storage {
  private final WebClient client;

  public WebStorage(final WebClient client) {
    this.client = client;
  }

  @Override
  public Publisher<ByteBuffer> load(final String key) {
    return client.get(String.format("https://myhost/path?query=%s", key))
      .rxSend()
      .toFlowable()
      .map(resp -> ByteBuffer.wrap(resp.body().getBytes()));
  }
}
```

This solution is not correct, since it's reading all body bytes in a blocking way with `getBytes()` call.

Is it possible to read response from Vert.x `WebClient` by chunks and convert it to `Publisher` (or Rx `Flowable`)?

Answer (score 2):

The Vert.x Web client is not designed to stream the response body. It buffers content by design.

If you want to stream the content, you can use the underlying HTTP client which is more flexible.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you can use [ByteCodec.pipe](https://vertx.io/docs/vertx-web-client/java/#_decoding_responses):

```
import io.reactivex.Flowable;
import io.vertx.ext.reactivestreams.ReactiveWriteStream;
import io.vertx.reactivex.core.Vertx;
import io.vertx.reactivex.core.buffer.Buffer;
import io.vertx.reactivex.core.streams.WriteStream;
import io.vertx.reactivex.ext.web.client.WebClient;
import io.vertx.reactivex.ext.web.codec.BodyCodec;
import org.reactivestreams.Publisher;

import java.nio.ByteBuffer;

interface Storage {
    Publisher<ByteBuffer> load(String key);
}

class WebStorage implements Storage {
    private final Vertx vertx = Vertx.vertx();
    private final WebClient client;

    public WebStorage(final WebClient client) {
        this.client = client;
    }

    @Override
    public Publisher<ByteBuffer> load(final String key) {
        final ReactiveWriteStream<Buffer> stream = ReactiveWriteStream.writeStream(vertx.getDelegate());
        client.get(String.format("https://myhost/path?query=%s", key))
            .as(BodyCodec.pipe(WriteStream.newInstance(stream)))
            .rxSend().subscribe();
        return Flowable.fromPublisher(stream).map(buffer -> ByteBuffer.wrap(buffer.getBytes()));
    }
}
```